# Sending REST request from react application

Tags: c#, reactjs, cross-domain, fetch

I'm trying to send REST request from rest application, but I'm getting 405 error.
My domain supplier had advised me to change the web.config file.

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

I've also used Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.cors, and added the line

```
config.EnableCors();
```

to WebApiConfig.cs
and added the headers

```
[EnableCors(origins:"http://localhost:3000",headers:"*",methods:"*")]
```

to my controller Action.

And on the client side I've tried using Fetch:

```
 const payload = {
            dos: "window",
            did: "123456",
            phone: userName,
            password: password
        };
        const options = {
          method: 'POST',
          mode: 'cors',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/jsonp',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(payload),

        };

        // SEND REQUEST
        fetch('myUrl/API/login_staff', options).then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
        });
```

But I'm getting the 505 error followed by:
Failed to load *myUrl*: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:3000, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled
How can I fix It?

Comment: I'm also responsible for the beck end server. So I'm the one who wrote the REST API.

Comment: Sounds like you want to test (using curl or some non-browser client) how the server responds to OPTIONS requests. Because I’m guessing that 405 error is likely not in response to your POST request but instead in response to the CORS preflight OPTIONS request that the browser automatically sends on its own before trying the POST request from your code.